# position image at bottom of <a> tag

Tags: html, css

How can I position an image to align with the bottom of an `<a>` tag?

I have:

```
<a href=""><img src="" /><span>text</span></a>
```

Right now, the image seems to extent above the `<a>` by a few pixels.

I tried:

```
img { vertical-align: bottom; }
```

but that moved it too far down.

Comment: Could provide us jsfiddle, because now I dont know how height <a> supposed to be or how big img should be etc

Comment: @SzymonDziewoński - sure, I'll put one together in a minute

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `vertical-align: baseline;`, which aligns the lower edge of the `<img>` element along the text's base-line, rather than `vertical-align: bottom` (which, as you've found, aligns the bottom of the `<img>` against the lower edge of the parent `<a>` element, which is a little lower than the `baseline`, in order to accommodate the descending portions of letters such as `g`,`p`,`q` and `y` should go).

So, I'd suggest:

```css
a img {
  vertical-align: baseline;
}
```

```html
<a href="#">
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/200/nightlife" /><span>text</span>
</a>
```

References:

- [`vertical-align`](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#propdef-vertical-align).

Answer (score 1):

If you look at my example here, you can see that they are in fact aligned:  http://jsfiddle.net/jzsmy629/2/

Adding a border will show you where your blocks are:

HTML:

```
<a href=""><img src="http://placehold.it/45x45" /><span>text</span></a>
```

CSS:

```
img { vertical-align: bottom; border:solid 1px black; }
span { border: solid 1px black; }
```

Comment: looks like `vertical-align: bottom` is where I went wrong. Thanks for the help